# Discord Python Bot only reacts on DM message

Tags: python, discord.py

Dear Community I tried my best but I cant find out why the bot only reacts on dm messages. Yesterday evening the bot worked fin and reacted to messages in a Discord but now he only reacts to dm´s. This code is just a short example of the on_message function I´m using but I cant find an alternative to on_message.

````
from timeit import repeat
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sqlite3
from discord.message import Message

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
PREFIX = '!'

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(PREFIX):
        
        if message.content == (PREFIX + "test"):
            await message.channel.send("test")





@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("GuMo!")


bot.run("Token")```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord bot works in DM but not in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056594/python-discord-bot-works-in-dm-but-not-in-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this probably has to do with the "intents" permissions that are being added to discord bots. Try

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

and also give the bot the message content intent on the developer portal https://discord.com/developers/applications

Answer (score -4):

If you install this:
**pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py**
Your bot will only react to messages send as DM.