# Python Discord bot works in DM but not in server

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to set up a simple Discord bot for a server, but it only appears to be responding in DMs to commands and not in any server channels. The bot has admin permissions in the server I am trying to get it to respond in.

After doing some looking around I have found no fixes.

Here's the code:

```
import discord

token_file = open("bot_token.txt", "r+")
TOKEN = str(token_file.readlines()).strip("[]'")
token_file.close()

command_prefix = ">"

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith(command_prefix):
        if message.content == ">help":
            await message.channel.send("What do you need help with?")
        elif message.content == ">hello":
            await message.channel.send("Hi there!")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("This command is not recognised by our bot, please use the help menu if required.")
    else:
        return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things must be done before you can respond to messages within channels:

- Configuration the intent of the bot within discord developer portal
- Specify the intent within the bot itself.

#### Step 1: Configuring the intent of the bot in developer portal:

Within the developer portal, find your bot under applications. Selecting the "bot" tab from the left, you'll see the following option:
[image]

It needs to be enabled.

If you try the below without enabling it, you will get a permission error:

> ... from None discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to
> https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable
> the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

#### Step 2: Specifying intent in the bot:

Specifying intent is done through the following lines. It is required in addition to the option being enabled in the developer portal.

```
    intents = discord.Intents.default() 
    intents.message_content = True
```

Discord added a message content intent that has to be used since the first September 2022. if you‘re doing a discord.py tutorial, be aware that it should be a 2.0 tutorial as many things have been updated since then.

Consider using the [commands extension of discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html) as it is handling some annoying stuff and provides more easier interfaces to handle commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm just wondering where in my code I should add the `discord.Intents.message_content = True`?

Comment: define a variable `intents = discord.Intents.default()`
Then `intents.message_content = True` and pass the intents variable to your client instance

Comment: I have done that, and it gives me this: TypeError: Client.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: You have to refer it as `intents` as it is a keyword argument and not a positional argument

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I have managed to sort it now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> @kejax has given absolutely the right answer I just want to add how u
> can make the use of **`'intent'`** in your code:-

---

#### If you want to listen and have access to all available events and data

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

> ***Full Code :-***

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('................')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!greet'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')
```

---

#### You can also specify specific intents by creating a set of the desired discord.Intents constants.

```
intents = {discord.Intents.guilds, discord.Intents.messages}
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

> ***Full Code:-***

```
import discord

intents = {discord.Intents.guilds, discord.Intents.messages}
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('....................')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!greet'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')
```