# Discord Python Bot only responds to dms

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot has admin perms, I have no idea why it would do this, seems really weird... any ideas would be great......

This code was generated by ChatGPT btw
Hsggsss hshsssggs
Shsyshgsvsvevsgs
Jshsgscsccsvshshshyw
Hshshsggsfsgs

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

# Define your phrases in a dictionary where the keys are the phrases
# and the values are the corresponding article names
phrases = {
    "Phrase 1": "Article 1",
    "Phrase 2": "Article 2",
    "Phrase 3": "Article 3",
    "Phrase 4": "Article 4"
}

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='phrase')
async def get_random_phrase(ctx):
    # Get a random phrase from the dictionary
    random_phrase = random.choice(list(phrases.keys()))
    article_name = phrases[random_phrase]

    # Send the random phrase
    message = await ctx.send(f"Here's a random phrase: {random_phrase}")

    def channel_filter(m):
        # Check if the message is correct and from the correct user and in the same server and channel
        return m.author != bot.user and m.guild == ctx.guild and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.lower() == article_name.lower()

    try:
        # Wait for a correct message for 30 seconds
        message = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=channel_filter)

        # If a correct message is received, send a response
        await ctx.send(f"{message.author.mention}, that is correct!")
    except:
        # If no correct message is received, send a timeout message
        await ctx.send("Time's up!")
```

```
I tried re inviting the bot to the server, but still won't work.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord bot works in DM but not in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056594/python-discord-bot-works-in-dm-but-not-in-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the `message_content` intent.
Add this to your code:

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

Also go to the Developer Portal https://discord.com/developers/applications and the bot section and enable `message_content`